# npm audit returns weird dependencies

Tags: javascript, npm, npm-audit

Npm audit returns output with some valid warnings, but also with weird dependencies that look like random hexadecimal strings. That string changes every time when I run `npm audit` and is identical for all packages, referenced in audit.

How can I get rid of that? Npm version is 6.8.0

```
High            Cross-Site Scripting (XSS)
Package         jquery
Patched in      >=3.0.0
Dependency of   28941ae593a0bfccfbff69e6c9be45d3edb864692c815174fff557331de…
Path            28941ae593a0bfccfbff69e6c9be45d3edb864692c815174fff557331de…
                >
                39e4d897653a99aeb635bac80469694d1066d648e1fc9d3ac63ded7789c…
                > jquery

More info       https://npmjs.com/advisories/328


Moderate        Prototype Pollution
Package         lodash
Patched in      >=4.17.11
Dependency of   browserify-resolutions [dev]
Path            browserify-resolutions > lodash

More info       https://npmjs.com/advisories/782

Moderate        Prototype Pollution
Package         lodash
Patched in      >=4.17.11
Dependency of   28941ae593a0bfccfbff69e6c9be45d3edb864692c815174fff557331de…
Path            28941ae593a0bfccfbff69e6c9be45d3edb864692c815174fff557331de…
                > lodash

More info       https://npmjs.com/advisories/782
```

Comment: Can you lookup those strings in the lockfile (package-lock.json or yarn.lock)? They look like hashes to me.

Comment: @MarouaneFazouane we do not use lock files and explicitly set that in .npmrc with `package-lock=false`.  Those are random with every `npm audit` call and not present in any file in my working folder (including node_modules)

Comment: Related issue [#1641](https://npm.community/t/sha-like-entries-in-npm-audit/1641)

Comment: Thank you, @RobC

Answer (score 2):

I just ran into the same issue. After looking into the [npm docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/commands/npm-audit#scrubbing) this has been resolved in Version 7. I just ran npm audit using npm 7+ and it has pointed to the exact packages that are the culprit with no hash.